# Generally proving that a sequence converges

Tags: solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I am looking for help to see if I understand proofs by epsilon-delta correctly. I want to prove that the sequence $\{b-\frac{33}{2n^2}\}$ converges to b. Where b is a real number.

I want to prove it with this definition of convergence $\forall\epsilon >0, \exists M>0$ s.t. if $n\geq M$ then $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$.

#### My work

I start by looking at

$$|b-\frac{33}{2n^2}-b|<\epsilon$$

To determine $\epsilon$, I start out by simplifying the expression on the left side

$$|b-\frac{33}{2n^2}-b|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow |-\frac{33}{2n^2}|<\epsilon$$
Since the b's eliminate eachother I remove those. I can also remove the negative because of the absolutes, thus I have got the following
$$|\frac{33}{2n^2}|<\epsilon$$
Since $2n^2$ can never be negative I can safely remove the absolutes which leaves me with (What if the sequence could be negative, should I look at it casewise?)
$$\frac{33}{2n^2}<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow n>\frac{\sqrt{33}}{\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{\epsilon}}$$
I can therefore let $M=\frac{\sqrt{33}}{\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ s.t. $n>M$ and therefore I can conclude that whatever the value of $\epsilon$, I can pick a M that is smaller or equal to n and thus this sequence converges to b.

Have I done it correctly, and where can I improve? I want to be as precise as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely perfect. And if $b-a_n$ happened to take also negative values, you would just have to write $-\epsilon<b-a_n<\epsilon$ (or equivalently $-\epsilon<a_n-b<\epsilon$) instead of just $b-a_n<\epsilon$.

Comment: @AnneBauval, awesome thank you. That makes sense!

Comment: This looks great, I just wanted to make a super-pedantic comment. You said "therefore I can conclude that whatever the value of , I can pick a M that is smaller or equal to n...", but this is really "I can pick an n that is greater than or equal to M" as per your provided definition of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

I think it suffices to show that $\frac{33}{2n^2} \to 0$.

Fix arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$.  If you choose $M > \sqrt{\frac{33}{2\epsilon}}$, you have the following:

$\frac{33}{2M^2} < \frac{33}{2(\sqrt{\frac{33}{2\epsilon}})^2} = \frac{33}{33/\epsilon} = \epsilon$.  Since you can make $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small and always find a suitable $M$, then $\frac{33}{2n^2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Since $\frac{33}{2n^2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $b$ is constant, then I think you have proven that the sequence converges to $b$.